# Mule Dataweave null check and array empty check of JSON payloads

Tags: arrays, json, mule, dataweave

Need to check null and empty array in Dataweave using filter or any other logic.

First check the parentId is null, we need to skip the particular JSON. If parentId is not null need to check the mobileContacts or emailContacts 
have the array of values. If mobileContacts and emailContacts have empty List we need skip the particular JSON values. If  any one have the value we need to process the records.

Input JSON:

```
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "age": 23, 
  "results": [
    {
      "parentId": "12345",      
      "notes": "proceed",
      "mobileContacts": [
        {
          "relationId": "12345",
          "callId": "3456213"
        },
        {
          "relationId": "12345",
          "callId": "12345"
        }
      ],
      "emailContacts": [ ],
      "initial": true
    },
     {
      "parentId": "435638",      
      "notes": "proceed",
      "mobileContacts": [ ],
      "emailContacts": [ ],
      "initial": true
    },
     {
      "parentId": null,      
      "notes": "proceed",
      "mobileContacts": [
        {
          "relationId": "12345",
          "callId": "3456213"
        },
        {
          "relationId": "12345",
          "callId": "12345"
        }
      ],
      "emailContacts": [ ],
      "initial": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Need below Output:

```
{
  "name": "XYZ",
  "age": 23, 
  "results": [
    {
      "parentId": "12345",      
      "notes": "proceed",
      "mobileContacts": [
        {
          "relationId": "12345",
          "callId": "3456213"
        },
        {
          "relationId": null,
          "callId": null
        }
      ],     
      "initial": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This doc shows an example of how to do something that's very close to what you're doing I think: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-examples#conditional-list-reduction-via-a-function Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    name: payload.name,
    age: payload.age, 
    results: payload.results filter ($.parentId != null and ((sizeOf $.mobileContacts) > 0 or  (sizeOf $.emailContacts) > 0))
}
```